# Stack Overflow C00000FD in MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using a Custom tree control derived class. Below is the code.

**CCustomTreeCtrl.h**

```
class CCustomTreeCtrl : public CTreeCtrl
{
public:
    BOOL Check;
    CCustomTreeCtrl();
    virtual ~CCustomTreeCtrl();

protected:
    //{{AFX_MSG(CCustomTreeCtrl)
    afx_msg void OnLButtonDblClk(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();
};
```

**CCustomTreeCtrl.cpp**

```
CCustomTreeCtrl::CCustomTreeCtrl()
{
}

CCustomTreeCtrl::~CCustomTreeCtrl()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCustomTreeCtrl , CTreeCtrl)
//{{AFX_MSG(CCustomTreeCtrl)
ON_WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK()
 //}}AFX_MSG
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CCustomTreeCtrl::OnLButtonDblClk(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
   char buf[255];
   FILE *stream;
   CString FilePath;
   TV_HITTESTINFO pHitTestInfo;
   pHittestInfo.pt = point;
   pHitTestInfo.flags = TVHT_ONITEMLABEL;
   HitTest(&pHitTestInfo);

   if(pHitTestInfo.hItem != NULL && !ItemHasChildren(pHitTestInfo.hItem))
   {
      RECT sRect;
      GetItemRect(pHitTestInfo.hItem,&sRect,1);
      CRect cRect(&sRect);

      if(cRect.PtInRect(point))
      {
         CTestApp* the = (CTestApp*)AfxGetApp();
         CMainFrame* pFrame = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();

         CString FileName = GetItemtext(pHitTestInfo.hItem);

         FilePath = pFrame->Filepath;
         strcpy(buf,Filepath);
         strcat(buf,Filename);
         strcat(buf,".ext");

         stream = fopen(buf, "r");

         if(stream != NULL)
         {
            fclose(stream);

            if(pFrame->isUpToDate(buf))
            {
               pFrame->DisplayFile(buf);
            }
            else
            {
               pFrame->CreateFile(buf);//-> Error in this line Exception: C00000FD Stack OverFlow
               pFrame->DisplayFile(buf);
            }
         }
      }

   }
}
```

The application exits on double click on a tree item.
When debugging, on stepping into the CreateFile function raises ans stack overflow exception.

If the file is up to date the `DisplayFile` function is executed properly.

The error is only when I call the `CreateFile` function. The function just writes some data to text file. On debugging, the exception is raised the minute I step into the function.

Call Trace (IDE VC6)

```
CCustomTreeCtrl::OnLButtonDblClick(unsigned int 1, Cpoint {x=150 y=104}) line 117
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
USER32! xxxxxxxx()
USER32! xxxxxxxx()
USER32! xxxxxxxx()
USER32! xxxxxxxx()
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
CTestApp::PreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * 0x00484cd0 {msg = 0x00000203 wp = 0x00000001 lp= 0x00680096}) line 563
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
MFC42D! xxxxxxxx()
WinMain(HINSTANCE__ 0x00400000, HINSTANCE__ 0x00000000, char * 0x00151f2e, int 1) Line 30
WinMainCRTStartup() Line 330 + 54 bytes
KERNEL32! xxxxxxxx()
```

CreateFunction

```
void CMainFrame::CreateFile(CString FileName)
{
    BeginWaitCursor();

    if(FileName.getAt(1) == 'L')
    {
        CMyDllA myDlla;
        myDlla.ConvertDataToFile(MyDataBasePath,FileName);
    }
    else if(FileName.getAt(1) == 'B')
    {
        CMyDllB myDllb;
        myDllb.ConvertDataToFile(MyDataBasePath,FileName);
    }
    else if(FileName.getAt(1) == 'D')
    {
        CMyDllD myDlld;
        myDlld.ConvertDataToFile(MyDataBasePath,FileName);
    }
    else if(FileName.getAt(1) == 'S')
    {
        CMyDllS myDlls;
        myDlls.ConvertDataToFile(MyDataBasePath,FileName);
    }

    EndWaitCursor();
}

//ConvertDataToFile Function reads data for a database performs calculations and writes report to a text file.
```

@Michael Walz Yes, the application crashes before hitting the breakpoint.

In Disassembly:

```
147       pFrame->CreateFile(buf);
00456B74 push ecx
00456B75 mov  ecx,esp
00456B77 mov  dword ptr [ebp-112A8h],esp
00456B7D lea  edx, [buf]
00456B83 push edx
00456B84 call CString::CString (0045da26)
00456B89 mov  dword ptr [ebp-11328h],eap
00456B77 mov  ecx, dword ptr [pFrame]
00456B95 call @ILT+1300(CMainFrame::CreateFile) (00401519)
```

As soon as i step into Create File function, in the variable window its showing "this  CXX0069: Error variable needs stack frame"

CreateFile Disassembly:

```
10040: {
0043F813 push ebp
0043F814 mov  ebp, esp
0043F816 push 0FFh
0043F818 push offset $L111205 (00465099)
0043F81D mov  eax, fs:[00000000]
0043F823 push eax
0043F824 mov  dword ptr fs:[0],esp
0043F824 mov  eax, 109DC8h
0043F830 call $$$00001 (0045e840)  //Breaks here and jumps to CHKSTK.ASM File
0043F835 mov  dword ptr [ebp-109DBCh], ecx
0043F83B mov  dword ptr [ebp-4], 0
```

Currently I don't have the source of the CMyDllx. Only the header and lib.
But I am also calling the same function from the application menu, it get carried out without any error. Its only when I call it using tree control, I face the error.

@IInspectable Sorry but this is work PC, and I cannot install any software in this machine.

Comment: Can you look at the call stack when it crashes?

Comment: Show us the `CreateFile` function. The problem is most likely there.

Comment: edited and updated the Question

Comment: @Antony so if I understood well, then if you put a breakpoint right at the beginning of the `CreateFile` function, the crash happens even before it hits that breakpoint ? If yes try to step info `CreateFile` in disassembly mode, this could give some clues. Otherwise I don't see anything wrong or suspicious in your code. Please show also the declaration of the `CMyDllx` classes.

Comment: Since `CTestApp::PreTranslateMessage` is in the call stack (presumably) you should post the code for it as well. And please set up your IDE to use [Microsoft's public symbol server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy(v=vs.80).aspx), so we don't have to guess about the call stack. If Visual Studio 6 doesn't support symbol servers, use [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063.aspx) to produce a meaningful call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0043F824 mov  eax, 109DC8h
0043F830 call $$$00001 (0045e840)  //Breaks here and jumps to CHKSTK.ASM File
```

`109DC8h` tells the tale, the argument passed to __chkstk() is the amount of stack space that CreateFile() requires.  0x109dc8 == 1,088,968 bytes.  No can do, that's more than the entire space available in the stack (1 megabyte).  So __chkstk() correctly slams the emergency stop button before your program hits the wall, CreateFile() will always fail.

Your snippet squarely points the finger at the guilty party, it is one of the CMyDllx objects that is too big.  Or more likely, all of them, needing a quarter of a megabyte each.  Rewrite the code to allocate them on the free store with the `new` operator.